# The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a small application that uses WCF to communicate with a webserver. This program is used by some 200 clients, and each client is sending in about 5-20 requests/min.

Looking at the error logs I often get:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:00:59.9989999

The requests are made as follows:

```
ClientService Client = new ClientService();
Client.Open();
Client.updateOnline(userID);
Client.Close();
```

This is the app.config

```xml
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IClientService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="PATH TO SERVICE"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IClientService"
            contract="IClientService" name="WSHttpBinding_IClientService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Of the "many calls" each day about 200-800 fail. And about n-1 are ok. I am very confused what the issue can be. Looking at the server stats, it's hardly building up a sweat - each request takes <2 sec to process. The data it's sending consists of "int" or "very small strings" - so, its not due to size, if it were - there should be a consistent failure..

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you hosting this service in IIS or is it hosted by a windows service or some other app ?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with timeout and quote settings in the config file?

Comment: Actually, I suggest turning on WCF tracing (as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and review the messages that are logged when these errors appear.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't use a session enabled binding if you are calling the service the way you've shown in your post. It's a waste of resources and adds overhead to the overall communication.

Comment: The service is hosted in IIS. I have tried playing around with timeouts and quota's - yes. (how do I disable sessions?)

Comment: @KasperWittrup:My mistake. reliableSession is already disabled.

Comment: @KasperWittrup I am experiencing the same in our prod environment only. Did you ever find a solution to this to find out why these connections are timing out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that your requests are queuing up on server before being handled and then starts to time out. You can try couple of things here to see exactly whats going on

1) Try throttling in your  WCF services e.g: Try increasing your concurrent sessions. Take a look
[WCF Throttling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33362/WCF-Throttling)

2) Try using PerCall rather than Using Sessions here to make sure that no session remains there.
 Here is what you can do on your interface to remove session

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="YOUR NAMESPACE", SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
```

and your contract classes implementing those interface

```
ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

AND .... You should enable tracing to see exactly whats going on .

Comment: Ive done what you suggested .. and ive let it run for about 15 min now.. Only one client is reporting issues.. (Same timeout issue).. I will let it run for some time and see if its only one client reporting the issues now.. if it is, then ill attribute it to his connection.. (aka.. its late)...

Answer (score 45):

Try adding the timeout values to both the service AND the client:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeName" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
    sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
```

Comment: It works. Easy and simple solution. I've set this on client & service. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Check this performance counter - `ASP.NET Requests Queued`.

One web application can host many web pages and services. IIS processes only 12 concurrent requests per CPU core by default.

This means that even if your service is fast but other pages/services are slow your request has to wait in queue before they are executed.

`ASP.NET Requests Queued` should be zero or close to zero.

See [Performance Counters for ASP.NET on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx).

Comment: Over 2 minutes - the maximum ASP.NET Requests Queued is 1.. ASP.NET v4 Requests queued is 0 (sits is running .NET 4)