# Why is my WCF Service timing out when I try to fill my datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, datatable

I have an MVC app wired up to a wcf service, I'm trying to make a todo list app that features tasks that are dependant on other tasks, I have so far had no luck with this but I have built a stored proc, which I'm now calling from my WCF service and giving a response back to the client.

At the moment, the client gives the following error upon being non-responsive for 1 minute;

```
"The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."
```

the code on my WCF service looks like this;

```
public DataTable GetAllDependantTasks(string id)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ToDoDatabase"].ConnectionString;
                    com.Connection = conn;
                    com.CommandText = "usp_GetAllDependantTaskInfoByID";
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader returnvalue = com.ExecuteReader();

                    if (returnvalue.HasRows)
                    {
                        //List<DataRow> items = new List<DataRow>();
                        dt.Load(returnvalue);

                      //  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                       // {
                         //   items.Add(row);
                        //}

                        return dt;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new RowNotInTableException();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Write error to log
                return new DataTable();
            }
        }
```

I am using an ASPX page on my front end, the offending code looks like this;

```
 private void LoadTasks()
        {
            // get the todo list items
            ToDoService.ToDoServiceClient client = new ToDoService.ToDoServiceClient();

            try
            {
               // List<ToDoService.ToDoItemContract> toDoItems = client.GetToDoItems("").ToList();


       List<string> Items = new List<string>();

             foreach(var row in client.GetAllDependantTasks("").Rows)
                {
                    Items.Add(row.ToString());
                }

                dlTasks.DataSource = Items;


                dlTasks.DataBind();

                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: Log error
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this? I would like to fill my datalist on the front end with the existing tasks plus the task they are dependant upon, i've tried to return a datatable from my wcf service to bind it to the list but it doesn't seem to like it!

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tested the stored procedure independently? Does it run? Also post your WCF interfaces and contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the data returned is a lot and it takes time. SqlCommand has a 15 seconds default timeout.

What if you try to do

```
com.Connection = conn;
com.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

This disable a timeout for connection and allows more time for the execution of the fill. Try to adjust it (the time is in millisecond) to not leave it running indefinitely if something goes wrong.

If not, try setting the operation timout of the webservice with

```
Webservice.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Setting it to a longer timespan since the default wcf timespan is 1:00 which is what is happening to you.

Comment: sqlcommand does not contain a definition for ConnectionTimeout apparently

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215513/c-sharp-wcf-the-request-channel-timed-out-while-waiting-for-a-reply

Comment: could it be due to the fact i'm returning a datatable?

Comment: @ReeceCottam I don't know. What it was in the end? Did you solved it?

Comment: @ReeceCottam Updated the answer

Comment: it turns out a Datatable isn't serializable into XML!