# Getting timeout error - increase the send timeout value on binding

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, iis-7, connection-timeout

WCF service returns timeout error as below.

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after XX:XX: XX increases the send timeout value on binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout

[image]

But I'm getting this error within 1min while browsing my website. And I have mentioned the timeout value set to 00:10:00 (10min) in binding configuration (web.config).

The same service is working in my local system but when I hosted in server then I'm getting this issue.
As I observed, SQL query takes around 1 min: 20sec time to execute in server.

Do I need to update anywhere those send timeout values?

Can you please suggest this?
Thanks.

Comment: That's on the client side (not the service side).  It's the send timeout on the `<binding/>` element of the binding associated with your client endpoint.  The whole roundtrip needs to complete within the send timeout time.

Comment: @Flydog57 is right, Flydog go ahead and write the comment as Answer!

Comment: You asked at a fortuitous time. I spent the day trying to track down a WCF timeout issue (I'm pretty sure my issue is in a proxy). But, in the process, I've read up and tested each of the various timeouts. I'll write it up when i get near a computer

Comment: I've checked client side binding timed properties. All are having 10min. closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because the send timeout on the client side (not the service side) is timing out.  The send timeout is configured on the `<binding/>` element of the binding associate with your client endpoint.

The entire roundtrip (from client to server, service-side processing and return trip back to the client) must be completed before the send timeout expires.

Comment: Client side i have sendtimeout with 10min.    And other times also 
 i have mentioned like -> closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"

Comment: @Jagadeesh: The other thing you might consider is the "executionTimeout" attribute on `<httpRuntime>` under `<system.web>` in your config file, but this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2008/03/10/why-changing-sendtimeout-does-not-help-for-hosted-wcf-services/ says it's not relevant any more.  If I were you, I'd write a log entry at the beginning and end of _every_ service implementation, and at every call site on the client side.  That message you are getting is the exact message you would get when your 10 min send timeout expires.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused not by a WCF connection timeout, but by a slow response caused by other issues, such as Binding configuration issues on the server and client side, a database connection failure. Try to check the database connection string and whether the WCF running account has permission to connect to the database.
Considering the following config.

```
<binding name="http" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>          
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I have web config file in Root folder, we are using same web config in all areas. I am able to launch the application and get data from database. If service is returns less no of records(like 1,2 records) then its working properly. But if i have 100 records then do action then SQL execution time takes 1min.20 sec. then i am getting this error.

Comment: I have cross verified in IIS Connection time out also. Its default is 120Sec. I have updated to 300sec. Now also i am getting same issue.

Comment: Please try the above configuration.

Comment: I have same config settings. Actually, recently we are moved to AWS-EC2 instance. EC2 is having IIS 10 but my local/old server is having IIS 8.   So, Do we need to changes any settings in IIS level?   Because same source code+config binding  settings is working in my local and my old servers.

Comment: check the related discussion, wish it is useful to you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215513/the-request-channel-timed-out-while-waiting-for-a-reply